# Bash completion for executable files in Emacs shell buffer

Tags: shell, emacs

Bash completion seems to work correctly for the PATH that is set when I start emacs, but if I change the PATH in an emacs shell buffer, I cannot seem to get Emacs to rethink its list of possible completions.

Is there some way to reinitialize Emacs view of the completions?

In a non-emacs shell, everything works as expected with the occasional hash -r thrown in for good measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using completion-at-point, there is a variable `exec-path` that maintains a list of the directories that are searched for executables.  `shell-command-completion`, which is by default part of `shell-dynamic-complete-functions`, searches those locations.

You can update that variable with new locations to search for executables, eg. `(push "<new-directory>" exec-path)`.

Comment: Manually setting exec-path provides the completions I am expecting. Is there a handy elisp function that sets exec-path based on the PATH environment variable? And, I noticed that describe-variable says that making exec-path buffer-local is risky -- but that seems like the ideal setup if you have different paths in different shell buffers, no?

Comment: I believe it is called risky since it could be used to manipulate your computer in dangerous ways when the buffer is visited, eg. if it set as a directory local variable or something.

Comment: There may be a handy function, I would look through `env.el`. It is also fairly simple to split the result of `(getenv "PATH")` by `path-separator` and do whatever manipulations. There is also https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell, although I never used it since I;m not on Mac